# Python convert (variable format) lines in text to csv

Tags: python, csv

I hope you can help me with this tough task, where I need to convert the lines  inside a txt file into a csv format.

Input:

```
Network object group 1
Description ADDED
 host 10.1.6.174
Network object group 2
 Description 2 
Network object group A
 Description 3
 host 10.1.4.4
 host 10.1.4.5
 host 10.1.4.6
 host 10.1.4.8
Network object group D
 Description 4
 host 10.203.1.16
 host 10.203.1.15
 host 10.203.1.119
 host 10.203.1.80
 host 10.203.1.215
```

to a csv like:

```
Network object group 1,Network object group 2,Network object group A,Network object group D
Description ADDED, Description 2 , Description 3, Description 4
 host 10.1.6.174,, host 10.1.4.4, host 10.203.1.16
,, host 10.1.4.5, host 10.203.1.15
,, host 10.1.4.6, host 10.203.1.119
,, host 10.1.4.8, host 10.203.1.80
,,, host 10.203.1.215
```

Note that there's always a Network group and a Description, but the host part may or not exist , so it can be of any size.
ps: these are "standard Cisco's network object group configurations"

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Where do you need help specifically?

Comment: It is more about a the logic part , how to go over this file and is able to break in blocks the content inside each "network group"...

Comment: The input file contains sequential "network groups". I'd parse them to a list of data structures. If you want to have an output that basically transposes this information (i.e. each group is a column), you can iterate that list for each line of output and only print the corresponding data.

Comment: Not sure how to :) 
It is really about how to have this loop that reads finds the first network group , and transpose it to a column till it finds the next network statement and start again in column b...
but how to do it in a python logic is what I am looking for :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd parse the network groups as a list of data structures (for simplicity, I'll use a `dict` with entries `"name"` for the name, `"desc"` for the description, and `"hosts"` for a list of hosts).
To output those network groups in a transposed way, i.e. each group in a column, you can iterate the list for each line of output, printing only the corresponding data in each line:

```py
import sys


def parse_network_groups(file) -> list[dict]:
    groups = []
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("Network object group "):
            current_group = {"name": line, "hosts": []}
            groups.append(current_group)
        elif line.startswith("Description "):
            current_group["desc"] = line
        elif line.startswith("host "):
            current_group["hosts"].append(line)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Cannot parse " + line)
    return groups


def print_network_groups(groups: list[dict]) -> None:
    print(",".join(group["name"] for group in groups))
    print(",".join(group["desc"] for group in groups))
    for i in range(max(len(group["hosts"]) for group in groups)):
        print(
            ",".join(get_element_or_default(group["hosts"], i, "") for group in groups)
        )


def get_element_or_default(list: list[str], index: int, default: str) -> str:
    try:
        return list[index]
    except IndexError:
        return default


if __name__ == "__main__":
    network_groups = parse_network_groups(sys.stdin)
    print_network_groups(network_groups)
```

Note that I didn't focus on the CSV generation, but just use `",".join(values)` – which may be good enough if the `values` don't contain `,` characters – as the question was *more about the logic part.*

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks immensely :) 
Ive made a few mods to work on a real obj config as it has other keywords but it was just perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to save your data as a csv. first you need to convert the data into a python Dict. Then you can use save it as a pandas DataFrame and then you could use `to_csv` to convert it into a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("file_name.csv")
```

Above the variable data should be a python dictionary.

example

```
data = {'column1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'column2':[2,3,41,56,7,4,5]}
```

Comment: Why using pandas instead of built-in csv writer? Then you don't need any extra module.